# How to store information in QAbstractTableModel that is not shown in the QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, tablemodel

I have followed the [Address Book Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html) to create my own TableModel and TableView.

My implementation is very similar to this example, except each entry in the table is a Patient struct that has an ID associated with it. This ID is not shown the TableView, but when modifications are made, I use the ID to save the changes in the filesystem.

This is the MyPatient struct

```
struct MyPatient
{
    qlonglong id;
    QString firstName;
    QString lastName;
    QString dob;
    QString sex;
    QString height;
    QString weight;
    QString dateModified;

    bool operator==(const MyPatient &other) const
    {
        return id == other.id;
    }
};
```

Here is the body of my addPatient() method to add a patient to the table:

```
insertRows(0, 1, QModelIndex());

QModelIndex index = this->index(0, 0, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.firstName, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 1, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.lastName, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 2, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.dob, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 3, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.sex, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 4, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.height, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 5, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.weight, Qt::EditRole);
index = this->index(0, 6, QModelIndex());
setData(index, patient.dateModified, Qt::EditRole);
```

With the current implementation, when I call the data() method to retrieve a patient, the ID field is 0, because the table does not store that value.

How can I store this ID value in the table without showing it as its own column in the TableView?

I have tried added another two lines to the addPatient method:

```
    index = this->index(0, 7, QModelIndex());
    setData(index, patient.id, Qt::EditRole);
```

But the setData detects the index value as invalid, as the columnCount of the table is 7 as that is how many columns should appear in the QTableView.

Thank you, please let me know if there is anything in my question I can clarify.

Comment: Why not just create your own [role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).  `Qt::UserRole` and above are user definable.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the role system. If you would like to post as answer, I can select your's as correct.